# to access a page that was published

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have Two Projects.
one of the project is an webapplication which i have published. I want to access this page Upload.aspx

I have created another project in a different solution. This project is an MVC 3.0 application. One of my actions has to access the page Upload.aspx
How do i access the published url and call the page Upload.aspx
any suggestion would be highly helpful

Comment: What do you mean "access" ? a link can "access" the page, a post back can also "access" the page.

Comment: when i mean access...I refer to using that page

Comment: What is mean "using" ? run the code behind ? and if yes, where the results will going to be ? You can not access the code on a different project, but you can send them a command to do.

Comment: well let me explain again probably with different wordings so that i know my question is being understood right :)
I have an ASP.Net page that is hosted on a servers. 
eg: http://myservername/TMReportInputUpload/Upload.aspx
this page handles the code to save file to db(the file that is uploaded)

I need to upload a file on button click. Am using a new mvc application which performs many actions/functinalities. one such functionality is to upload a file. and i just need to refer that url by passing the file from input

Comment: As you describe it its sound that you only need to change on the `<form... ` the action to that page